# Zookeeper setup in c++

Tags: c++, cmake, apache-zookeeper

I have an application in C++ which is connecting with zookeeper in C++ with [this library](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/tree/master). Now I am struggling to integrate it with my C++ application.

I have `CMakeLists.txt` as below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(meta-flare-cpp)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/zookeeper")


add_executable(meta-flare src/main.cpp src/ZooKeeperConnector/ZooKeeperConnector.cpp)

# Link against ZooKeeper library
find_package(ZooKeeper REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(meta-flare ZooKeeper::ZooKeeper)

# Include directories
target_include_directories(meta-flare PRIVATE ${ZooKeeper_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I am not sure what mistake I am making, I have directory structure like this.

This is project structure

```
--- Folder Structure ---
CMakeCache.txt
CMakeLists.txt
[cmake]
    └── [Modules]
        └── FindZooKeeper.cmake
[src]
  ├── [ZooKeeperConnector]
    ├── ZooKeeperConnector.cpp
    └── ZooKeeperConnector.h
  └── main.cpp

[lib]
    └── [zookeeper]
        ├── zookeeper_github_clone
```

When I am doing `cmake .` Its giving following error ->

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
By not providing "FindZooKeeper.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"ZooKeeper", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ZooKeeper" with
any of the following names:

ZooKeeperConfig.cmake
zookeeper-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ZooKeeper" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"ZooKeeper_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"ZooKeeper" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can’t comment on the issue you’re facing, but an in-tree build is an awful idea.

Comment: Yeah, I have very basic understanding about the c++ development.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory of `FindZooKeeper.cmake` to your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Say your `FindZooKeeper.cmake` is in this location, `cmake/Modules/FindZooKeeper.cmake`.

You can set

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules")
```

Source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#id6

Comment: I have added but now it is giving following


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "meta-flare" links to target "ZooKeeper::ZooKeeper" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?